# Call custom Action after plugin installed or after rebooting the IDE - Eclipse plugin development

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I need to implement following scenario to my plugin and I couldn't find a proper tutorial. I'm new to eclipse plugin development, please share any tutorial available that I can follow

1. Once the install is complete and before eclipse is restarted, the user should be promoted with my custom preference screen.
2. if prompting the user can't happen before reboot, please prompt the user once eclipse has been rebooted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [startup extension point](http://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fextension-points%2Forg_eclipse_ui_startup.html). It declares the class that gets control when workbench UI is ready after start. In your implementation of `org.eclipse.ui.IStartup` you:

1. Check if that is a first start of your plugin (that can be done using any approach that you like, you can use 'first start' preference item for that, for example);
2. If it is first start you show custom preferences screen and update 'first start' preference item to false, so next start you now there is no need for custom dialog to appear.

Be aware:

1. There might be other startups that show modal dialogs;
2. Use Display.asyncExec() or Job.schedule() to avoid blocking thread that process startup extensions.

Here is real example [Usage Reporting in JBoss Tools](https://github.com/jbosstools/jbosstools-base/blob/master/usage/plugins/org.jboss.tools.usage/plugin.xml#L5).